# Installing Ipopt for anaconda python windows 64bit

Tags: windows, anaconda, tdm-mingw, ipopt

I'm trying to install **Ipopt** using **mingw64(TDM-GCC)** in **Windows 64bit**. I'm thinking about using it in **anaconda python**.
I closely followed instructions here (http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node15.html#SECTION00045300000000000000), but I couldn't compile it at all.

I used **reference BLAS/Lapack sources**, and compiled them together with Ipopt.
I got the message that ***configuration is successfully done***, but when I tried to make it, I kept getting the error message that *

> dasum.lo requires libcoinblas library

*.

I also tried to connect it to **Intel MKL library(lp64,latest version)** instead of compiling reference libraries, but it gave me an error

> "Makefile:272: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop"

. 
Ipopt version:3.12.4
Reference BLAS/LaPack version:3.6.0

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried solution here([link](http://ascend4.org/Building_ASCEND_for_64-bit_Windows#IPOPT)) with IPOPT 3.12.4, but it gave me error while making Lapack library. Error messages are: "No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.", "[all-recursive] Error1"

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -y -c pycalphad cyipopt
```

Executing this in an anaconda prompt should complete the installation of ipopt using cyipopt for python in anaconda.